# AADSTS700054: response_type 'id_token' is not enabled for the application

Tags: azure-active-directory

Using adal.js v1.0.17 and Web API via JavaScript.
Running a custom tab within Microsoft Teams and getting this error when trying to authenticate.
Looked at the app registration within Azure portal and not seen anything there that could help.  Tried to edit the manifest file and change the value of oauth2AllowImplicitFlow to true but still getting error.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Found the solution.
Need to access the Azure portal using Chrome.
Go to Azure Active Directory and choose App Registrations (Preview).
Open up the app registration and choose Authentication on the left.
Under Advanced Settings, Implicit grant check the box "ID tokens".

That will add the property oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow to the manifest file with the value set to "true".

Comment: Did you have issues doing this with other browsers?

Comment: Did this not work for anyone else? I have this enabled and still get the issue

Comment: Yes, tried this in Edge and the App Registrations (Preview) page doesn't work for it.  Not sure about Firefox

Comment: TheDream So you are getting the same error as I describe above with the id_token?

Comment: @OskarJenssonFjeld What do you see when you try to access App registrations (Preview) using Edge? Do you see an error?

Comment: Worked for me, but I could swear I had already changed oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow  in manifest before, so it must be doing else besides changing that setting. Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

you can try by enabling the 'ID Token'

[image: Enabled the 'ID Token']

Comment: This option is now removed from the UI. You have to go to the Manifest option, and set the  "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow" property to true.

Comment: Hey @SatThiru - I see that option in my UI. Could there be different versions of the portal running for different people?

Comment: Funny, I'm using ASP.NET core and it says it right in the details above the checkbox, who reads instructions? ;)  "ID Token is needed for ASP.NET Core Web Apps."